# How to serialize kiebase in drools-engine 8.43.0.Final

Tags: java, drools, rules, rule-engine

Since the SessionsAwareKnowledgeBase implements KieBase which can't be serializable.

Usecase: Need to serialize the kiebase and store into the cache (redis). At runtime i have to deserialize the kiebase.

Kindly help me out on this.

Tried with Marshalling kiesessions and save it in the cache, But when pulling out from the cache we need even kiebase to unmarshall.

Comment: If you want to precompile the rules beforehand then executable model might be an option with Drools 8.x

Answer (score 0):

The `KieBase` is not serializable anymore in Drools 8.x.  This is an [explicit decision](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/pull/3929) of Drools' authors.  If you really need the serialization you should consider downgrading to the latest 7.x release (actually [7.74.1.Final](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-bom)).  Also note that versions from 7.45.0.Final to 7.66.0.Final have a [serialization-related bug](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-6850).